# leading bit in binary32 float(IEEE)

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, bit

the background for question - [specifications of binary32 float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

My question is about assumption, that first (leading) bit is always 1, so we do not need to store it. That's true, but it has another role in number.. we know, where it starts. So after extracting that first non-zero bit, we don't know where number starts, unless there's another non-zero bit right afterwards.

In that wiki article, they use number (1.100011)binary. So fraction is 100011 and we can build up that number back without problem. However, what about (1.000011)binary? we extract 1 and we're left with 000011, and as we can't store leading zeroes inside zero-initialized bitfield, we get 11. But what happens, when we want to build it back? we get 1.11 and that's wrong.

So how we can freely extract that leading bit in arbitrary number?

Comment: The number of leading zeroes is implied by the size of the bitfield.

Comment: Sure you know where it starts.  It starts at that leading 1.  Append the rest, don't shift the zeros away.

Comment: imagine zero filled bit field 00000000... copy there 000011.. you get 00000011... no shifts ;) And you still don't know how much zeroes there were in first place

Comment: and @raymond chen - you have fixed 23 bits bitfield for fraction in binary32.. how you can implicitly use that size?

Comment: Write a number in binary. Any number. If what you write down starts with zeros, throw them away. See if doing so changes the number.

Comment: @David Hefferman as I wrote in question - sure it does: 1000011 is my number.. extract leading bit 000011.. throw zeroes away 11.. rebuild the number.. 111 - From 67 to 7.. because I've lost these zeroes and can't rebuild correctly. Maybe I miss something so don't hessitate to point it out

Comment: My answer points it out. You don't throw away the zeros after you have stripped the leading one. You keep them.

Comment: and the way to do this is... I should've point out that we're talking there about practical application..

Comment: The mantissa is stored in a 23-bit field. The value you have is 11. That is only 2 bits. Therefore there must be 21 leading 0 bits. Remember, it's a fixed-size field. There are 23 bits being stored. If the value you want to store is only two bits, then the other bits are zero. Those are the leading zero bits.

Comment: BUT.. where to append that 1.. when building number back.. if you put it in front you get 1-21 zeroes-11.. and tha'ts, again wrong... and I don't store the info how much leading zeroes there were

Comment: Put the 1 in front of the mantissa. The mantissa has 23 binary digits.

Comment: okay.. let's do it the other way.. I got number (1000011)binary - that are 7 binary digit's.. could you, please, write down that number inside this 23 bits bitfield(00000000000000000000000), after extracting leading 1? and afterward, how to append back that leading 1.

Comment: Are you forgetting about the exponent?

Comment: You would never put the number 1000011 into the mantissa of a floating point value because it is not normalized. (There must be a single 1 before the binary point.) If the mantissa is 1.00011, then that is encoded as [1.]00011000000000000000000 where the leading 1 and binary point are not actually stored. When reading back, the value is 00011000000000000000000. The implied leading 1 and binary point are restored, yielding 1.00011000000000000000000 as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, what about (1.000011)binary? we extract 1 and we're left with 000011, and as we can't store leading zeroes inside zero-initialized bitfield, we get 11.

In fact you do store leading zeros. What is stored is 000011 and when the 1 is added back in you are back where you started. Storing the leading zeros (after the leading 1 has been removed) is what makes it work.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting upvotes.. You can't store 000011 inside bitfield.. you can store just 11 (or anything else - 110,1100 - but it must start with 1). You can't store leading zeros. What's the difference between set to leading zero and initialized to zero? There's only difference if 0 is after 1. The only possible assumption is that we use full size of bitfield but then, how you store 7 digit number with leading 0 in, for example 10 digit bitfield? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by bitfields. There are just 23 bits set aside for the mantissa. Each one is well identified and ordered. They can all be zero, or all one, or any other pattern.

Comment: @Raven: "I don't know why you're getting upvotes." Because David knows what he's talking about, and you don't. Why don't you look at the binary representations of a few floating-point numbers, and see for yourself?

Comment: "bitfield = ordered array of bits.. in c++ it's std::vector<bool>". I understand how bitfields can look like.. last shot. Imagine binary numbers 10011 and 111, and 2 bitfields of 4 bits(0000).. So, according to IEEE we can extract leading 1. We get 0011 and 11 (in fact we can't get 0011 because it's instantly 11, but that's what you write). Now, store it in bitfield: first number looks like 0011, second 0011. They are exactly same! But 10011 and 111 aren't the same.

Comment: @Raven: Why don't you look at the binary representations of a few floating-point numbers, and see for yourself?

Comment: think of the mantissa as an array of bits, `bit[23]` in pseudo-code. You can, and do, store leading zeros. That's really all there is to it. Once you add back the implicit leading 1 it's all good.

Comment: @TonyK I just did.. ad I found what I've expected... but it looks like I had my idea of how float numbers work quite wrong.. anyway this seems like good answer at last